# An error in the book "noncommutative ring" writed by Herstein

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

I'm reading the book "noncommutative ring" writed by Herstein.
In the page 15, 
the author says that

Let $F$ be a field and $A$ is an algebra over $F$.

Let $\rho$ be a maximal regular right ideal of $A$ 
considered as a ring.
We claim that $\rho$ is automatically a subspace of $A$ over $F$.
If not, $F\rho\nsubseteq F$;
however, 
from the defining properties of an algebra $F\rho$ is a right ideal of $R$.
By the maximality of $\rho$ we conclude that $A=F\rho+\rho$.
Thus $A^2=(F\rho+\rho)A\subset(F\rho)A+\rho A\subset\rho(FA)+\rho A\subset \rho$.
Since $\rho$ is regular there is an $a\in A$ such that $x-ax\in \rho$
for all $x\in A$;
but $ax\in A^2\subset \rho$ leaving us with the contradiction that $\rho=A$.
Having now established that every maximal regular right ideal of $A$
as a ring is a maximal regular right ideal of $A$ as an algebra we conclude, 
on invoking
Theorem 1.2.2, 
that the algebra radical of $A$ coincides with the ring radical of $A$.

There are two typing errors.

1. "$F\rho\nsubseteq F$" should be "$F\rho \nsubseteq \rho$"
2. "$F\rho$ is a right ideal of $R$" should be "$F\rho$ is a right ideal of $A$"

My question is the sentence "$F\rho$ is a right ideal of $A$."
The author assumes that $F\rho\nsubseteq \rho$.
Hence there exists $f_0\in F$ and $x_0\in \rho$ 
such that $f_0 x_0\notin\rho$.

If $F\rho$ is a right ideal of $A$, 
then for all $f_1, f_2\in F$ and $x_1, x_2\in \rho$, 
$f_1 x_1+f_2 x_2\in \rho$.
($F\rho$ is an additive abelian group, 
so the additive closure holds.)

Let $f_1=f_0, x_1=x_0, f_2=0$.
Then we get a contradiction.

Is it right?
(I mean my argument.)

Comment: How are $A$ and $F$ related? Quite possibly $R$ should be $A$ since $R$ is not otherwise mentioned.

Comment: I think it is a typing error.
The author does not mention $R$ before.

Comment: @Mark Bennet
Thank you, I have explained the notation $F$ and $A$.